# Encrypting boot SSD and data drive

Tags: ssd, encryption, truecrypt, disk-encryption

I use a 120GB SSD as my boot/system drive, and I have a 1TB SSHD that I use as a data drive. Many of my applications are stored on the SSHD, and Windows does not function properly if the data drive is not connected. How can I use TrueCrypt (or another encryption program if recommended) to encrypt both then decrypt both at boot? I'm running the Windows 10 Technical Preview.

My drives do not support TPM, so I cannot use BitLocker unless I dedicate a USB flash drive to be a key for the system, which I am not a fan of (I'd rather not have to worry about unlocking with a physical device).

Comment: Have you looked into bit locker? It should be sufficient. However, please do not count on it as you're running a technical preview.

Comment: I know of BitLocker, but I hadn't thought much about it--the NSA leaks and whatnot have left me a little leery of it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Bitlocker, It's really easy to set up and does exactly what you need.  Also as you are running the technical preview it is probably safer to use then a 3rd party method at the moment.

As to your worries about NSA Leeks and such - Truecrypt has been broken, is no longer in development and even have a method of migrating from truecrypt to bit locker on their front page.

Or you could use Veracrypt, this is a fork of truecrypt and still in active development, https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/ ... you may need to hunt round for documentation and help, but it will let you encrypt a whole existing drive/volume in its volume creation wizard

Comment: TrueCrypt hasn't been broken--it's been tentatively shown by an external audit to be secure, though they haven't gotten through all of the code yet. The project has just been abandoned. No one knows whether there are backdoors in BitLocker, and since it's proprietary Microsoft code it's likely that no one ever will. Also, my drives do not support TPM, so I would need to use a USB key to unlock my drives at boot time, which is not an option I'm a big fan of. (Just updated the OP to specify this.)

Comment: Fair enough - but i would suggest veracrypt instead, i have updated my answer